# Error in integrator function of the MUESLI numerical library

Tags: fortran, integration, ode, numerical

I am trying to use the numerical integration function of the MUESLI library, mfOdeSolve, but I get a compilation error.
Just like in the example (#4-52) of the user's guide, I divided the code into a main program and an external module:

Main:

```
program ode
     use odemod
     use fml

     real (kind = MF_DOUBLE) :: t_0, t_end
     type(mfArray) :: t_span, y_0, y_end

     print *, "integration of {y'' = - y} over [0,pi]:"
     print *, "  [ solution is: y(t) = sin(x) ]"

     t_0 = 0.0d0
     t_end = MF_PI
     t_span = .t. mfLinSpace( t_0, t_end, 10 ) 
     y_0 = [0, 1]

     y_end = mfOdeSolve( deriv, t_span, y_0)
     call msDisplay( y_end, "numerical result" )        
end program
```

Module:

```
module odemod
    use fml

    contains
    subroutine deriv( t, y, yprime )
        real(kind=MF_DOUBLE), intent(in) :: t, y(*)
        real(kind=MF_DOUBLE)             :: yprime(*)

        yprime(1) =  y(2)
        yprime(2) = -y(1)
    end subroutine
end module
```

The module compiles with no problems, but I get the following error for the main program:

> y_end = mfOdeSolve( deriv, t_span, y_0)
>
> ```
>        1
> ```
>
> Error: There is no specific function for the generic 'mfodesolve' at (1)

I looked at the reference manual, but still can't fix this. Any ideas?

User's Guide: http://people.irisa.fr/Edouard.Canot/muesli/muesli_user_guide.pdf

Reference Manual: http://people.irisa.fr/Edouard.Canot/muesli/muesli_ref_manual.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Page 41 of the Users Guide (the first PDF) indeed shows the example (#4-52) that

```
! definition of a user-subroutine (actually in an external module)
subroutine deriv( t, y, yprime )
   real(kind=MF_DOUBLE), intent(in) :: t, y(*)
   real(kind=MF_DOUBLE)             :: yprime(*)
   yprime(1) =  y(2)
   yprime(2) = -y(1)
end subroutine
...
```

However, page 371 of the Reference Manual (the second PDF) describes the interface for `mfOdeSolve` as

```
function mfOdeSolve( deriv, t_span, y_0 [, options, jac, sparse] ) result( out )
    interface
        subroutine deriv( t, y, yprime, flag )
            real(kind=MF_DOUBLE), intent(in)     :: t, y(*)
            real(kind=MF_DOUBLE), intent(out)    :: yprime(*)
            integer,              intent(in out) :: flag
        end subroutine
    end interface
    type(mfArray),       intent(in)           :: t_span, y_0
    type(mf_DE_Options), intent(in), optional :: options
    external,                        optional :: jac
    logical,             intent(in), optional :: sparse
    type(mfArray) :: out
```

So the definition of the dummy subroutine argument `deriv` seems slightly different in that (1) `intent(out)` is attached on `yprime`, and (2) it has the `flag` variable also. This latter manual also describes how to set `flag` in detail.

So, possibly the first PDF manual has not been updated yet...? You might try the second definition above and see if the expected results (in the first manual) can be obtained.

```
subroutine deriv( t, y, yprime, flag )
   real(kind=MF_DOUBLE), intent(in)    :: t, y(*)
   real(kind=MF_DOUBLE), intent(out)   :: yprime(*)
   integer,              intent(inout) :: flag   !! no modification (as a test)
   yprime(1) =  y(2)
   yprime(2) = -y(1)
end subroutine
```

Answer (score 1):

The reference manual (page 371) shows that the first argument, `deriv`, of `mfOdeSolve` should be a subroutine that has four arguments.

Your code (and the example in the user manual) only has three arguments.

There should be an additional `integer, intent(inout) :: flag` dummy argument for `deriv`.

(The compilers complaint is a little misleading - the characteristics of the arguments of a dummy procedure are not used for generic resolution - just the "procedureness" and (if the procedure is known to be a function) the type of the function.  Consequently the compiler could directly complain about the mismatch in dummy argument characteristics of the actual procedure.)